# Unsupported operand type 'list' and 'float'

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

from math import *

f2 = open('C:\\Users\\Audrey\\Documents\\samplestats data.txt')

lines = f2.readlines()

f2.close()

x1 = []

for line in lines:
    p = line.split()
    x1.append(float(p[0]))


#First we can find the mean
mean=(sum(x1)/len(x1))


print mean

#Next the sample variance (s^2). We use the mean which is 3.74

samplev=((sum(x1-3.74)**2)/(10-1))

print samplev
```

Something is wrong with the sample variance, how can I get around it?

Comment: `sum(x1-3.74)` should do what? Did you mean `(sum(x1) - 3.74)` or possibly `sum(x - 3.74 for x in x1)`?

Comment: I'm trying to find the summation of x1-3.74, would sum(x -3.74 for x in x1) work?

Comment: As described by @minitech, If you want to subtract 3.74 from each element of the x1 list then yes, `sum([x-3.74 for x in x1])`will work. If you want to subtract 3.74 from the sum of element contained in x1, then `sum(x1) - 3.74` is the code to execute!

Comment: @ohe: Pedantic: For the `sum` of each value minus `3.74`, for efficiency, you'd probably want either (Python bits only) `sum(x - 3.74 for x in x1)` (avoids creating intermediate `list`) or for speed, you might convert to a `numpy` array to let it do more work for you in C: `x1 = np.array(x1)`, `mean = x1.sum() / len(x1)`, `samplev = (x1 - 3.74).sum() ** 2 / (10 - 1)`. `x1 - 3.74` actually does element-wise subtraction when `x1` is a `numpy` array.

Comment: @minitech: Given they import `numpy`, I suspect they meant to convert `x1` to a `numpy` array at some point, where `x1 - 3.74` would do element-wise subtraction (though in that case, they should call the `.sum()` method on the result that would sum entirely in C superfast, not the `sum` built-in function that would have to iterate and sum Python level `float`s.

Comment: thank you all the 'sum(x - 3.74 for x in x1)' works